# Targeting next component node in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-table

I'm currently building an expandable table component in React and am looking for a way to target the next adjacent component. See example:

```
<TableRow>
    <TableData>
        Purchase
    </TableData>
    <TableData>
        4 432,00
    </TableData>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TableData wrapper={true} colspan={2}>
        <SubTable>
            <SubRow>

                //CONTENT//

            </SubRow>
        </SubTable>
    </TableData>
</TableRow>
```

I essentially want to target a show/hide on the TableRow immediately following the first TableRow component. Is there a simple way to do this at all?

Comment: You want an accordion?

Comment: Yes essentially looking for an accordion table using React components

Comment: See this https://codepen.io/adamaoc/pen/wBGGQv and change to tablerows maybe?

Comment: Get a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the component and do what you got to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css, if I get your question correctly in the first block you can use state to change the toggle:

```
            <TableRow onClick={
                 //if hasChild ?
                 //boolean toggle code :
                 //pass empty function into the onClick to do nothing.
                 // ' '  }>
                <TableData>
                  Purchase
                </ TableData>
                <TableData>
                  4 432,00
                </ TableData>
            </ TableRow>
```

Then in the second block you can use the toggle to show or hide the block:

```
             <TableRow class={toggle ? 'show': 'hide'}>
               <TableData wrapper={true} colspan={2}>
                  <SubTable>
                    <SubRow>

                      //CONTENT//

                    </ SubRow>
                  </ SubTable>

                </ TableData>
              </ TableRow>
```

In your css you will have to write up some code for the .show and .hide classes. You can use css [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This part will work great for showing/hiding the rows. However I also want there to be some flexibility for mapping each row to a list of data, some of which may or may not have sub level rows. Essentially some of my rows will have the option to show hide their 'child' content if it's there, and if not then they will remain static rows. What would be a flexible way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you know on render which rows have children and which ones are static ?

Comment: Yes, there would be an object with the relevant information on render

Comment: Then you can use that to determine if the onClick is going to do anything at all. in the onClick function have an if statement that says:  hasChild ? // boolean toggle code : ' '. Do you want me to edit my answer with this in mind ?